# DivIcon vertical text

Tags: leaflet, text, icon, vertical

Iam struggling with one letter below the other vertical text orientation for DivIcon. Found some hints/hacks here https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text

But i couldnt manage to get it working for me. My result was that the letters just lay above each other. Is that even supported for DivIcon? Another possibilty would be to create a DivIcon for each letter. But thats very unusual i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like posted in this thread  [codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/LxJVNQ](http://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/LxJVNQ) and pointed out by IvanSanchez this works fine.

```
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size:1em;
  width:1em;
  padding:0 0.9em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  cursor: vertical-text;
```

Just make sure not to add `line-height:`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, CSS transforms work on block elements, not on inline elements, so you'll have to wrap the contents of your `DivIcon` into a block element to apply a transform.

Furthermore, Leaflet uses CSS transforms internally to position the marker's icons, so any transform applied to the outer marker container may conflict with any CSS-provided transform.

A more reliable (and easier) way to have "vertical text" is to use the [`writing-mode` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode), like so:

```
/* CSS */
.vertical-text {
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

---

```
// JS
var marker = L.marker([0, 0], {
  icon: L.divIcon({
    className: 'vertical-text',
    html: 'Null Island'
  })
});
```

[image]

See a [working example here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wusek/edit?html,output).

Comment: Mh thats a start. But im looking more likely for something like here http://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/LxJVNQ

Comment: That's a trivial copy-paste, hon. https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/mibi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: You're right! My problem was line-height:0px; This lead to the overlaying letters.